# Getting NullPointerException when passing the current activity to a class

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an object called gm and setting a property called a in a class to the activity.

```
 //This is in the Activity
 GameConfiguration gm = new GameConfiguration();
 gm.setA(this);
```

And then in the class I'm doing this.

```
public class GameConfiguration {

private Activity as;
public TextView tx;


public void setTextsTextViews(){

    Activity b = getA();
    tx = (TextView) b.findViewById(R.id.category);
    tx.setText("Test");

    //
}

public Activity getA() {
    return as;
}

public void setA(Activity a) {
    this.as = a;
}
}
```

The class GameConfiguration is a parent of 2 clases and in those 2 I'm just calling the method setTextsTextViews, I though this would work but I'm getting a NullPointerException error in this line

```
  tx = (TextView) b.findViewById(R.id.category);
```

What I don't understand is that when I do this,

```
 public void setTextsTextViews(Activity a){

    tx = (TextView) a.findViewById(R.id.category);
    tx.setText("Test");

    //
}
```

Passing the activity from the child class it does work, I don't know I'm new to all of this, thank you if you can help

Comment: Are you sure that you call
`setContentView()` inside your `onCreate()` method before you actually calling to `setTextsTextViews()`?

Comment: Just use the debugger. Probably either `b` or `R.id.category` is `null`. Find out which is `null`, and then look why.

Comment: Yeah b is null thats what I'm not getting, why is it null if a set it before?

Answer (score 0):

You get nullPointerException because the view contains R.id.category is not showing in these moment. Passing a view instead activity to the GameConfiguration class and make sure that the correct layout is inflate.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Passing a view works, passing the TextView I want to change works perfect, but what I want is to pass the activity so I can find the TextView in the GameConfiguration class and use the method in the 2 child class

Comment: The layout that contains the TextView is showing when you want change the TextView? I thing the problem is because the layout is not inflate.

Comment: Okay, I kinda patched it, in the Activity I was creating the GameConfiguration object I'm too calling a method of one of the child classes, so what I did was pass the activity to that method and in that method call setA() and set the activity in the GameConfiguration class and it worked, I don't know if you understood but you helped so thank you.